# /DateTime field for birthday in symfony forms

Tags: php, symfony

I need to retrieve the birthday of a student from the database and set it as the birthday of a student entity. Then I need to load that data to a form.

```
$birth_day = strtotime($student_[0]['birthday']);
$birth__day = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$birth_day); 
$student->setBirthday($birth__day);
```

And in the form builder I have used the below code

```
add('birthday', 'birthday',array(
            'data' => new \DateTime(),'placeholder'=>'-SELECT-'))
```

Instead of the birthday that particular student, it shows the today's date.

Can someone please explain what should I do to load the birthday instead of the today's date.
Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Remove 'data' => new \DateTime().

Comment: Removing that part gives an error saying _Unable to transform value for property path "birthday": Expected a \DateTime or \DateTimeInterface._

Comment: That means that whatever be in the birthday property of the student it's not a DateTime value, also for that reason when you force to use new DateTime it work. Also must work when you set $student->setBirthday(new \DateTime()); . So check the value and fix it.

Comment: I think your question is very unclear. What you're trying to do? Update an entity?

Comment: @felipsmartins yes I need to load the details of a student into the form to edit the details and update the profile.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the 'data' option, you are setting the default value for the field so in your example you are setting it to a new Datetime (today).

Here is the symfony doc page about it http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#data

Like @abdiel suggested, remove the data part.